# REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose

Tags: android, deployment, google-play-console

Google Play Support keeps Rejecting the last deployment of my App.

Below I'm quoting the reason for the reject:

> Issue found: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core
> purpose. We found that your app is not compliant with how
> REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is allowed to be used.
> Specifically, the use of the permission is not directly related to the
> core purpose of the app.
>
> Additionally, follow these steps to bring your app into compliance:
>
> Please remove the use of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission from your
> app.

After removing an unused package that was using the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission, I tried to re-deploy but I've kept getting the app rejected.

I can confirm that the current list of used permissions does NOT include the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.

On play.google.com, I checked the permission lists of the last uploaded versions (see attached screenshot).

I also unpacked the lastly uploaded SDK file (using apktool), and searched "REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" in the extracted folder; of course, no results were found.

Has anyone any suggestion on how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: The same issue occurred with me. My app's previous versions included this permission but in the latest update, I removed them but still received rejection message via mail. More confusing thing is that on the play console dashboard, there's no inbox of rejection information and my app's update status is in review. Still trying to figure out what to do next?

Comment: Please post an update, even I got the same error where we do not have anything.

Comment: I think we need to deactivate the apks that are in various tracks which include this REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission by uploading new version valid apks in different tracks.

Comment: i confirm the answer of Preetam Pal, i had the same issue and this permission was in a previous version in the test track, after making an update in that track the prod version was validated by google

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The same issue occurred with me. My app's previous versions included this permission but in the latest update, I removed them but still received rejection message via mail. Then I found that in the other track (internal testing track), I had an apk with REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission. This was the main cause of rejection of my app update. I observed that the form 'App bundles and APKs using sensitive permissions' was showing the internal track's apk information regarding the use of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES.

So, I tried to deactivate my previous internal track's apk with the new version (that didn't include any REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGE permission). Now when I open my form page 'App bundles and APKs using sensitive permissions' again.

[image]

Now, it showed that no app bundle or apk uses this sensitive permission.
Hope that it could solve this issue. I am too waiting for my update to be approved.

Comment: @PreetamPal - where in the console are you seeing the _form page  'App bundles and APKs using sensitive permissions'_ (ie - your screenshot)?

Comment: In the policy section of your app, you will find 'App Content'. On clicking 'App Content', you will find a section 'Sensitive permissions and APIs' which needs to be filled if you are using sensitive permission. There you can check if any of your APKs might be having this permission through 'View app bundles and APKs' option.

Comment: @PreetamPal - Hello can you help me to resolve this i see 3 version in view app bundles and APKs. can you suggest me what i need to do for approved application

Comment: Ya you just need to deactivate your APKs in all the tracks (check either in open testing, closed testing or internal testing tracks. You need to have valid APKs in all those tracks. Any single track with the latest APK containing SENSITIVE Permission Request will again cause App rejection). Just build your signed APK after increasing your version number and removing those SENSITIVE requests and deploy them to your respective tracks.

Comment: Thanks Mate.. i have uploaded a new build for Internal testing and promoted it to Open Testing. asap that gets approved myissue will be resolved and then i can promote new build to production

Answer (score 6):

- First step, Check in your manifest merger file if the specified
  sensitive permission is shown. Check in release variant. (Most likely
  not, if yes, remove this permission)
- Second step, In playstore, Go to app bundles explorer and check if
  any of the **older app bundles** have this permission and is still
  active. If yes. you have to provide an update to this track. *It is
  unfortunate that Google play review email does not mention that issue can
  be in an older app bundles or other tracks*
- Provide an update to playstore.

Note, If you want to forcefully remove this permission (if you do not care
which library is adding it)

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove"/>
```

If none of the above works. You have to write them an email and clarify.

Comment: yes, the second step is crucial. Indeed, is very unfortunate they don't mention this crucial detail.

Comment: hi, how to update older app bundle ?